# Sorting pair of integers

Tags: c#, .net, sorting, graphics, quicksort

I have a list with ~100k of integer pairs like these ones:

```
0, 12
0, 14
0, 1
0, 8
0, 2
0, 4
0, 3
1, 5
1, 11
1, 8
1, 2
2, 7
2, 9
2, 4
2, 5
2, 13
3, 12
3, 10
3, 4
3, 6
...
```

I need to sort them like

```
0, 1
0, 2
0, 3
0, 4
0, 8
0, 12
0, 14
1, 2
1, 5
1, 8
1, 11
2, 4
2, 5
2, 7
2, 9
2, 13
3, 4
3, 6
...
```

Currently I am doing:

```
myList.Sort(comparer);
```

when the comparer is defined as:

```
class EdgeIntersectComparer : IComparer<EdgeIntersect>
{
   public int Compare(EdgeIntersect l1, EdgeIntersect l2)
   {
       if (l1.V1 < l2.V1)
          return -1;
       if (l1.V1 > l2.V1)
          return 1;

       if (l1.V2 < l2.V2)
          return -1;
       if (l1.V2 > l2.V2)
          return 1;

       return 0;
   }
}
```

What can I do to improve execution speed? Is there any smarter approach to the problem?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Tested `myList.OrderBy(e => e.V1).ThenBy(e => e.V2)` and it's slower.

Comment: Currently the list is sorted by the first integer of the pair...

Comment: @Chris: Edges are defined as a pair of integers...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I sort a List<T> by multiple T.attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4875737/how-can-i-sort-a-listt-by-multiple-t-attributes)

Comment: I don't know if it would be faster (probably not) but you could try using Linq:  `var sorted = myList.OrderBy(e => e.V1).ThenBy(e => e.V2);`

Comment: "What can I do to improve execution speed? Is there any smarter approach to the problem?"... Not sure if anyone is reading that part.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719719/fastest-safe-sorting-algorithm-implementation might be usefull.

Comment: Note: you can compress you comparer a little bit:
`public int Compare(EdgeIntersect l1, EdgeIntersect l2) => l1.V1 != l2.V1 ? l1.V1.CompareTo(l2.V1) : l1.V2.CompareTo(l2.V2);`, but I rather doubt about any performance improvement using this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had commented in a deleted post that `V1` is already sorted.

> In addition by V1 the list is already sorted.

I did a test using data already ordered by V1, but with V2 initialized with random numbers. I found this faster than your method:

```
myList = myList.GroupBy(x => x.V1).SelectMany(x => x.OrderBy(y => y.V2)).ToList();
```

This *only* works if `V1` is already sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a possible option you coult try an Array instead of a List. (it depends on your context). If you can't:

Asuming:

```
 public class Pair
{
    public int First { get; private set; }
    public int Second { get; private set; }
    public Pair(int first, int second)
    {
        this.First = first;
        this.Second = second;
    }
}
```

And how the List is already ordered by the first item, maybe something like this? not sure if this will be faster:

```
    public static List<Pair> FullOrderedList(List<Pair> SemiOrderedList)
    {
        List<Pair> FList = new List<Pair>();
        List<Pair> demi = new List<Pair>();
        int MaxNumber = SemiOrderedList.Count;
        int compared = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < MaxNumber; i++)
        {
            int first = SemiOrderedList[i].First;
            if (compared == first)
            {
                demi.Add(SemiOrderedList[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                compared++;
                FList.AddRange(demi.OrderBy(x => x.Second));
                demi.Clear();
            }
        }
        return FList;
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

A small speed increase can be gained by optimizing your comparer:

```
if (l1.V1 == l2.V1)
{
   if (l1.V2 > l2.V2) return 1;
   else return -1;
}
else if (l1.V1 < l2.V1)
          return -1;
else return 1;
```

max 2 statements to check, rather than your 4.